# Set UILabel text using KVC

Tags: ios

How to set UILabel text using KVC in iOS ? 
Suppose I have following lines of code :

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UILabel *nameLabel;

[self setValue:@"someName" forKeyPath:@"nameLabel.text"];
NSLog(@"Using KVC :Output name label - %@",[self valueForKeyPath:@"nameLabel.text"]);
/* Returns nil */
```

Answer (score 0):

Seem like I found the fix. UILabel must be on subview, either by dragging and dropping on the storyboard and creating IBOutet or by programatically adding it on the subview.
So, `@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *nameLabel;` did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *nameLabel;

[self setValue:@"Testing123" forKeyPath:@"nameLabel.text"];
```

[See the image below of the storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/miMuG.png)